# cast with linqToEntity(Esql)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-sql

my code :

```
public List<Book> GetBook(string NameField, object Value)
    {
        var queryESQL = @"select VALUE Book from Book
                 where Cast(Book." + NameField + " as string) like '%M%'";
        var query = this.Entities.CreateQuery<Book>(
                  queryESQL);
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

error :

> Type 'string' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas
>   are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type
>   name, line 2, column 51.

**update :**

new code :

```
public List<Book> GetBook(string NameField, object Value)
    {
        var queryESQL = @"select VALUE Book from Book
                 where Cast(Book." + NameField + " as EDM.string) like '%M%'";
        var query = this.Entities.CreateQuery<Book>(
                  queryESQL);
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

error :

```
Type 'EDM.string' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 2, column 51.
```

Answer (score 8):

The `CreateQuery<>` method uses the CLR types, instead of EDM types, so use `System.String` instead of `EDM.String` in the query.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Although I can't understand why Edm.String doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use `Edm.String` instead of `string` when casting.

Comment: error : Type 'EDM.string' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 2, column 51.

Comment: @mrJack: Did you make sure you capitalized the `S` in `EDM.String`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior : yes .I am sure